Web BroadcastChannel fails in iframe when src is redirected
I have an iframe with src attr set to https://example.com/path. This URL redirects 301 to https://othersite.com/path. This page loads some JS and creates a BroadcastChannel with a listener on it. It then opens a new window to https://othersite.com/path2. This page load some JS that creates a BroadcastChannel with the same name and does a postMessage. The problem: it never arrives in the iframe. The weird thing is, it does work if the src of the iframe is not a redirect. But that doesn't make sense because even though it is redirected, the origin is determined by the page that is eventually loaded. So the origins are the same (yes I checked that), and the BroadcastChannel names are the same. So why doesn't this work??
Edit: I have found a reproduction scenario:
Ok, I have a reproduction scenario. Run this code on your machine (install express first npm init and npm i express). Then add the following hosts to your /etc/hosts (the domains are important, it seems to work when they are subdomains of the same domain): 127.0.0.1 api.rubbish.wow accounts.rubbish.wow google.wow my.rubbish.wow my.site.wow and run this:
const express = require('express');

// Server 1 (Port 4000)
const server1 = express();
server1.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
    <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src="http://api.rubbish.wow:4001" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});
server1.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Server 1 listening on port 4000');
});

// Server 2 (Port 4001)
const server2 = express();
server2.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, 'http://accounts.rubbish.wow:4002/iframe-content');
});
server2.listen(4001, () => {
  console.log('Server 2 listening on port 4001');
});

// Server 3 (Port 4002)
const server3 = express();
server3.get('/iframe-content', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Iframe Content</h1>
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <button onclick="openNewWindow()">Open New Window</button>
        <script>
          function openNewWindow() {
            window.open('http://google.wow:4003');
          }

          const channel = new BroadcastChannel('auth');
          channel.onmessage = (event) => {
            const messageDiv = document.getElementById('messages');
            const newMessage = document.createElement('div');
            newMessage.textContent = 'Received message: ' + event.data;
            messageDiv.appendChild(newMessage);
          };
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

server3.get('/new-window', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>New Window</h1>
        <button id="sendMessageButton">Send Message</button>
        <script>
          const channel = new BroadcastChannel('auth');
          document.getElementById('sendMessageButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            channel.postMessage('Authentication successful');
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});
server3.listen(4002, () => {
  console.log('Server 3 listening on port 4002');
});

// Server 4 (Port 4003)
const server4 = express();
server4.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('http://accounts.rubbish.wow:4002/new-window');
});
server4.listen(4003, () => {
  console.log('Server 4 listening on port 4003');
});

Open http://my.site.wow:4000 in your browser, open the window and try to send the message -> FAIL
Open http://my.rubbish.wow:4000 in your browser, open the window and try to send the message -> SUCCESS
So when origin of the iframe and the origin of the top level page are both subdomains of the same domain (rubbish.wow) it works, otherwise it doesn't and I don't have a clue why not.

I'd have thought It was supposed to work indeed... A few questions: has the iframe a sandbox  attribute? How is the new page to path2 opened exactly? From this scenario it seems you shouldn't even need a BroadcastChannel since both the iframe and the opened window should be able to communicate directly.

So I just tested on my side and it does work as expected when the iframe isn't sandboxed and no COXP headers are sent. Please share more details about your actual setup.

@Kaiido the new window contains the Google OAuth2 flow where a user logs in and gives consent to use my service. The redirect_uri for that flow redirects to https://othersite.com/path2. The iframe does not have a sandbox attribute and the window is opened using window.open. I will try make a reproduction repo.

@Kaiido what are COXP headers? Never heard or seen that term before.

@Kaiido I added a reproduction scenario to the original question

By COXP I meant all of the COOP, CORP, COEP, headers. So I can indeed reproduce in every browser what you experience, so it must be "per specs". I must admit I'm at a complete lost however. It simply doesn't make sense to me... As I thought you don't even need a BroadcastChannel, because the popup and the iframe are same-origin and can communicate with each other directly. opener.document.getElementById("messages").append("success"); from the popup will print "success" in the iframe. So I really don't understand why the BC aren't matching... I'll ask around.

The reason this happens is because BroadcastChannel is partitioned by the site of the top-level document (through which your document is embedded). In the popup document it's not partitioned.
Although this is yet to be properly standardized, it's already implemented this way in most implementations.

You are the best. This was impossible to debug and find the cause.
